# Qt designer how to set style?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I made an application in Qt designer and I can also preview it in "fusion" style.

How can I make it always look like in the "fusion" style? I mean like set it as the standard design. (I'm using Python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set the style to the app

```
.... 
app = QApplication([])
app.setStyle('Fusion')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! All I found were 20 minute videos which don't even work for me! Now this is very simple and working.